# The right way to structure my c++ project with cmake?

Tags: c++, compilation, makefile, cmake

I have been struggling with this for quite a while, and my adventures with cmake have only resulted in hackish solutions that I am pretty sure are not correct.

I created a library that consists of several files, as follows:

```
-libfolder
  -codepart1folder
    -CMakeLists.txt
    -codepart1.cpp
    -codepart1.hpp
  -codepart2folder
  -codepart3folder
  -lib.cpp
  -lib.hpp
  -CMakeLists.txt
```

I wrote a CMakeLists file to compile the library (after some experimentation), and I can generate a lib.a file. Now I would like to include this code as a library in other projects, and access it through the interface in lib.hpp. What is the best way to do this, in terms of directory structure, and what I need to put into CMakeLists.txt in my root project?

My current attempt has been to add -libfolder as a subfolder to my current project, and add the commands:

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libfolder)
link_directories(${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/libfolder)
add_subdirectory(libfolder)
target_link_libraries(project lib)
```

When I run make, the library compiles fine, but when project.cpp compiles, it complains that it cannot find codepart1.hpp (which is included in lib.hpp, included from project.cpp).

I suspect that this is the wrong way about doing this, but I cannot wade through the CMake documentation and find a good tutorial on setting up projects like this. Please help, CMake gurus!

Comment: Perhaps not very helpful for cmake per-see, but I would advice you to take a look at premake. It's nearing maturity and have many advantages to cmake ( one being that it's a heck of a lot faster to get up to speed with it, especially if you already know lua ). You can check it out at http://industriousone.com/what-premake .

Comment: so, do you want to enable your new project to use the previously built library, or do you want to build both from a sortof meta-project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after consulting a coworker of mine who is a CMake guru, it seems CMake does not have support for what I am trying to do, leaving one with 3 options:

1. Add all of the dependencies to the parent projects CMakeLists.txt - not very clean, but it will get the thing to work. You'll have to do this for every project you add the code to, and go back and fix things if your library changes.
2. clean up your library headers. This is done through some compiler hackery. The idea is to forward-declare every class, and use only pointers or boost::shared_ptr, and then include the dependencies only in the cpp file. That way you can build the cpp file using all the findpackage stuff, and you get the bonus of being able to use the lib by only including the header and linking to the library.
3. Look into build systems. Having portable code and fast code compilation with complex dependencies is not a solved problem! From my investigations it turned out to be quite complicated. I ended up adopting my coworkers build system which he created himself in cmake, using things he picked up from Google.

Comment: +1, because cleaning up your interface such that it does not need3 rdparty include-dirs is even better.

Answer (score 5):

The clean way to import one CMake project into another is via the [find_package](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3afind_package) command. The package declaration is done by using the [export](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:export) command. An advantage of using find_package is that it eliminates the need to hard-code paths to the package's files.

Regarding the missing hpp file, you didn't include codepart1folder, so it's not on the include path.

Comment: Ok... from this answer it is not really clear to me whether find_package and export are the right things to use in this case, or how I would do so. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: use include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libfolder/codepart1folder)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your post you don't seem to add 'codepart1folder' to the includes anywhere. How are you including codepart1.hpp as:

```
#include <codepart1.hpp>
#include "codepart1folder/codepart1.hpp"
```

I don't think there is a standard accepted way to structure cmake projects. I've looked at a bunch of cmake repos and they tend to have differences. Personally I do the following:

```
-project
    CMakeLists.txt
    -build
    -cmake
         OptionalCmakeModule.cmake
    -src
        -Main
            Main.cpp
            Main.hpp
        -DataStructs
            SomeTree.hpp
            SomeObject.hpp
        -Debug
            Debug.hpp
        -UI
            Window.hpp
            Window.cpp
```

Basically that dumps all the source code into 1 directory, then you perform an out of source build with: '**mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make**' in the projects root folder.

If you have separate libs as part of your project, then you might want a separate libs directory with another subfolder for your specific lib.

I have some of my repos on: https://github.com/dcbishop/ if you want to look at the CMakeLists.txt files.

The main problems with my project structure are that I use the FILE_GLOB which is apparently the 'wrong' way to do things (if you add files after running '**cmake ..**' then they won't be picked up hen you do a '**make**'). I haven't figured out what the 'right' way to do it is (from what I can see it involves keeping a separate list of files) I also only use 1 CMakeLists.txt file.

Some projects also choose to separate their cpp and hpp files into separate directories. So you would have an include and src folders (at least for the hpp files that are intended to be used externally). I think that would mainly be for projects that are mainly large libraries. Would also make installing header files much easier.

Comment: codepart1folder is included in the CMakeLists.txt file inside libfolder. It seems wrong to me to have to add all of the subfolders, includes and links in the CmakeLists.txt in the project folder, since project.cpp does not depend on any of them - only lib.hpp does.

In your tree, imagine that there's a project2 that defines a library and I want to use project2 as a subpart of project.

Comment: @JohnSavage. But it is the right way... I would create a LIB_INCLUDE_DIRS variable in the lib-project, which is "exported" to the CMakeCache containing all the necessary dependent include-dirs. Then assume that variable will be present when cmake-ing Project.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/libfolder/codepart1folder)
```

In such a case you might want to [`set( CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR on)`](http://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables) to add all folders to the include directory path variable.

Check cmake's output on the command line whether the correct include folders are set or not. Additionally you can always use `message()` as "print debugging" for cmake variables.
In case of include directories however you need to read the directory property to see what is actually in the include directories.

```
get_property(inc_dirs DIRECTORY PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
message("inc_dirs = ${inc_dirs}")
```

I hope this helps you figuring out what is missing.

**Edit**

I just saw your comment about added codepart1folder in the libfolder. It is only available in the libfolder's include_directory path and not propagated to the root folder.
Since the include codepart1.hpp is present in the lib.hpp however you need to have it also available in the project path otherwise you will get missing declaration errors when you build your project.

Comment: Ok, so this is my issue. I feel like I shouldn't have to go and re-include all of my subfolders in the parent project. lib is a self-contained piece of code with its own CMakeLists.txt, and compiles fine into lib.a. I don't want to have to wire it all into every project I want to use it in.

Comment: Then you should properly interface your lib.